# texstudio spell checking

Tags: spelling

I encounter problems with spell checking with my texstudio. I've looked at some of the questions and answers in this website. I followed some of the instructions provided in the answers but still does not solve my problem.

I download the latest version (I think) of the texstudio-2.10.8.

Then I go to Options--->Configure TeXstudio. Then I looked at the "Language Checking" for the spell check and dictionaries, the screen shot is the following
[image]
I set the "Default Language" to be "en_GB" (originally, it was de_De). Then I clicked “Ok”. I think I am all set.

However, when I go back to my tex file, I choose part of a sentence "Note that the initial point" and then I go to "Tools"--->"Check Spelling", it tells me that it couldn't recognize the word "that", and suggest me to replace it by "tat". The screen shot is the following
[image]
This drives my crazy, I don't know where I missed something important.

Comment: have you closed and reopened Texstudio?

Answer (score 11):

It has been almost a year and this question has not been marked as answered yet, therefore, I have to point to the obvious solution of re-downloading the English dictionary, with a version that you are certain it is complete. New OpenOffice English dictionaries can be found in the link provided by **@sreeraj t**, also found [here](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/english-dictionaries-apache-openoffice).

Then unzip the `.oat` file or, if you cannot do it directly, change the extension to `.zip` and unzip it to the directory that TexStudio is referencing. You should be all set.

Answer (score 6):

I also face the same problem. But i could rectify it with
[Please follow the link](http://www.rohitfarmer.in/computing/linux-and-open-source/how-to-make-dictionary-work-in-texstudio/.)
But,as pointed out by @MaartenDhondt and @Zarko, the link based answer will become obsolete when the link doesn't works. So, I would like to modify my earlier answer by **taking exactly the same thing given in the website.**

> I recently started using LaTex for my PhD thesis. I would say it takes a while to get your head around it but once it works it’s a fun thing to do. And it is so much easy to work with large documents such as a thesis than using MS word or LibreOffice writer. I am using TexStudio as my LaTex IDE and honestly speaking I find it better than others available for the same purpose. One of the advantages is that you can use dictionary for spell checking and in contrast to TexMaker (which is the main source code on which the TexStudio is built) you can also add words in the dictionary. I use my office computer as well as my laptop to write my thesis and I wanted that if I add a word using my office computer TexStudio it also get added to my laptop dictionary as well. I figured out that the best way to do this is if I can make the same dictionary access to both the computers. So I used the Dropbox to store the dictionary files. TexStudio works with the OpenOffice dictionary. So here are the steps to make the dictionary work in TexStudio.
>
> Step 1: Download the OpnOffice dictionary (http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/english-dictionaries-apache-openoffice). The download file will be an .oxt archive, which can be open using any archive manager. Extract the en_GB.aff and en_GB.dic files (I am using English Great Britain).
>
> Step 2: Create a folder in Dropbox say dictionary and move the extracted .aff and .dic file to this folder.
>
> Step 3: Now open TexStudio and click on the menu Options > Configure TexStudio.
>
> Step 4: On the General tab look for the section Dictionaries. And give the path to the dictionary in the Dropbox folder. It will automatically show the dictionaries available in that folder for you to choose. And you are done.

Answer (score 4):

In the bottom-right corner you can change languages:
[image]

To ensure this *.tex-file is always in en_GB add a "magic comment"
[image]

Ensure that `% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB` is insered (before `\documentcass`), if not add/change it by hand

If it does not work, try restarting texstudio

Comment: For me it was bottom-right corner, next to the zoom functionality. Windows 10